# Finding time difference when a is bigger than b

Tags: python

When a and b are close the code works fine. I tried it with 2359 as a and 1 as b and it gave the correct number of hours but gave 1438 minutes instead of 58. I know that is because its not changing the minute value for a. Any advice to fix this. I also tried a method adding % 1440 but it didnt work.

```
numA = int(input("A departs at: "))
Ahours = numA // 100
Aminutes = numA % 100
numA = Ahours * 60 + Aminutes

numB = int(input("B departs at: "))
Bhours = numB // 100
Bminutes = numB % 100
numB = Bhours * 60 + Bminutes

diffMin = abs(numB - numA)
diffHours = diffMin // 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently sets diffMin to the total number of minutes between time a and time b. This includes the multiple hours between the two times. To make it not do that, either subtract the appropriate number of minutes:

```
#get numB
#get numA
diffMin = abs(numB-numA)
diffHours = diffMin // 60
diffMin -= 60*diffHours
```

Or you can use modulus 60:

```
#get numB
#get numA
diffMin = abs(numB-numA)
diffHours = diffMin // 60
diffMin %= 60
```

You can also use the datetime module which has some really great features for handling dates and times

Comment: Oh that makes more sense thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the line `numB = Bhours * 60 + Bminutes` shouldn't read `trainB = Bhours * 60 + Bminutes`?

Also, why go to all the trouble to compute `trainA` and `trainB` and then not use them when calculating the diff at the end?